# buscar un producto segun 2 tablas (MYSQL/PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo 2 tablas (productos,productos_lotes):
[image: Productos]
[image: Productos_lotes]

Lo que deseo es buscar (LIKE %) en la concatenacion de PRODUCTO.producto y LOTE.nivel1 y LOTE.nivel2

Por ejemplo si producto es **Buso Adidas** y en la tabla "productos_lotes" este id tiene como nivel1: **Talla S** y nivel2: **Color Azul** primero juntar estos 3 campos en uno solo: **Buso ADidas talla S color azul** y a este nuevo concact realizarle el where con un like %...%

El codigo que estoy intentando usar es:

```
"SELECT P.producto
FROM productos_lotes L
LEFT JOIN productos P ON P.id_producto = L.id_producto
WHERE CONCAT(P.producto,L.nivel1,L.nivel2) LIKE '%".$busqueda."%'
";
```

No me muestra ningun error pero tampoco me muestra alguna coincidencia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando [concatenas campos y valores](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) no puedes incluirlos como parte de los filtros, debes usar [HAVING](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx/).

Ahora, el problema es que los campos de nivel pueden contener valores nulos y el resultado de concatenar también será nulo, por lo que debes usar [COALESCE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) para asignar cadena vacía a cada campo que pueda ser nulo.

```
SELECT P.id_producto, P.producto, L.id_lote
    CONCAT(P.producto, ' ', COALESCE(L.nivel1, ''), ' ', COALESCE(L.nivel2, '')) as nombre_completo
FROM productos P
LEFT JOIN productos_lotes L
    ON P.id_producto = L.id_producto
WHERE P.estado = 1
HAVING nombre_completo LIKE '%$busqueda%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás intentando es equivalente a realizar el `like` por separado en cada uno de los campos, opción que te funcionará correctamente:

```
"SELECT P.producto
FROM productos_lotes L
LEFT JOIN productos P ON P.id_producto = L.id_producto
WHERE P.producto LIKE '%".$busqueda."%'
OR L.nivel1 LIKE '%".$busqueda."%' 
OR L.nivel2 LIKE '%".$busqueda."%'
";
```

Es decir, encuentra filas donde en alguno de los campos exista la condición.

Comment: si lo e pensado pero me parece (no tengo certeza) que hacerle un like a 3 campos a la vez consume mas recursos que concatenarlos y de alli buscar con un solo LIKE (es solo mi opinion)